# DISTINCT query not working its give me repeated columns on output

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

Buddy

i have one query of MSSQL.
that is like this..

```
SELECT DISTINCT resource.locationurl, 
                resource.resourcename, 
                resource.anwserid, 
                checktotal.total 
FROM   resource 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Count(DISTINCT anwserid) AS total, 
                          resourcename 
                   FROM   resource AS Resource_1 
                   WHERE  ( anwserid IN (SELECT Cast(value AS INT) AS Expr1 
                                         FROM   dbo.Udf_split(@sCategoryID, ',') 
                                                AS 
                                                udf_Split_1) ) 
                   GROUP  BY resourcename) AS checktotal 
               ON resource.resourcename = checktotal.resourcename 
WHERE  ( resource.anwserid IN (SELECT Cast(value AS INT) AS Expr1 
                               FROM   dbo.Udf_split(@sCategoryID, ',') AS 
                                      udf_Split_1) 
       ) 
       AND ( checktotal.total = @Total ) 
ORDER  BY resource.resourcename
```

I run this query but its give me repeated column of Resource.LocationURL.

you can check it live hear http://www.ite.org/visionzero/toolbox/default2.aspx

check in above link where you can fire select some category but result was not distinct..

i try most of my but now i am out of mind please help me with this.

Comment: To answer the question we also need an answer to a question. How are you defining distinct?

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand what `DISTINCT` means when you are fetching more than one column.

If you run this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2 FROM table
```

You are selected every different *combination*. An acceptable result would be

```
value 1_1, value 2_1
value 1_1, value 2_2,
value 2_1, value_2_1
```

In this example, `value 1_1` appears twice, but *the two columns combined* are unique.

My guess is that you are actually attempting to perform a grouping:

```
SELECT resource.locationurl, 
       resource.resourcename, 
       resource.anwserid, 
       Sum(checktotal.total) 
FROM   resource 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Count(DISTINCT anwserid) AS total, 
                          resourcename 
                   FROM   resource AS Resource_1 
                   WHERE  ( anwserid IN (SELECT Cast(value AS INT) AS Expr1 
                                         FROM   dbo.Udf_split(@sCategoryID, ',') 
                                                AS 
                                                udf_Split_1) ) 
                   GROUP  BY resourcename) AS checktotal 
               ON resource.resourcename = checktotal.resourcename 
WHERE  ( resource.anwserid IN (SELECT Cast(value AS INT) AS Expr1 
                               FROM   dbo.Udf_split(@sCategoryID, ',') AS 
                                      udf_Split_1) 
       ) 
       AND ( checktotal.total = @Total ) 
GROUP  BY resource.locationurl, 
          resource.resourcename, 
          resource.anwserid
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the site you linked doesn't do anything.

Second, `DISTINCT`ensures unique rows. It will not make the values in all the columns unique as well. Just think about it! How would it work? You have two rows with the same `locationurl` field, but with otherwise **distinct** elements. Which one do you not include?

Lastly, please take greater care in phrasing your questions.

Answer (score 0):

as I see your query is select DISTINCT on multi columns,
so if any record has at least one col difference then it pass the DISTINCT condition

Ex:

```
record1 : locationurl |  resourcename | anwserid  | Sum(checktotal.total)
             loc1         res1          1                100
record2 : locationurl |  resourcename | anwserid  | Sum(checktotal.total)
             loc1         res1          2                100
```